# KeyboardInterrrupt numpy - OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 2 of 4: Operation not permitted

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, numpy

We are facing this error in our Django API service where ElasticSearch uses numpy as a dependency. It's been working just fine for a over a year and suddenly started giving error.
I have tried all possible solutions that I could find but nothing seems to be helpful.

```
File “/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/REPLACED-wGPJvZ3g-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-
packages/elasticsearch/transport.py”, line 31, in <module>
from .serializer import DEFAULT_SERIALIZERS, Deserializer, JSONSerializer
File “/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/REPLACED-wGPJvZ3g-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/serializer.py”, line 35, in <module>
import numpy as np
File “/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/REPLACED-wGPJvZ3g-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py”, line 141, in <module>
from . import core
File “/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/REPLACED-wGPJvZ3g-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py”, line 23, in <module>
from . import multiarray
File “/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/REPLACED-wGPJvZ3g-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py”, line 10, in <module>
from . import overrides
File “/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/REPLACED-wGPJvZ3g-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py”, line 6, in <module>
from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
KeyboardInterrupt
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File “/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/REPLACED-wGPJvZ3g-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py”, line 82, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File “/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/REPLACED-wGPJvZ3g-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py”, line 69, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File “/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/REPLACED-wGPJvZ3g-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py”, line 170, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File “/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py”, line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File “<frozen importlib._bootstrap>“, line 1030, in _gcd_import
File “<frozen importlib._bootstrap>“, line 1007, in _find_and_load
File “<frozen importlib._bootstrap>“, line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File “<frozen importlib._bootstrap>“, line 680, in _load_unlocked
File “<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>“, line 850, in exec_module
File “<frozen importlib._bootstrap>“, line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File “/usr/src/REPLACED/REPLACED/settings.py”, line 15, in <module>
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
File “/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/REPLACED-wGPJvZ3g-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/__init__.py”, line 36, in <module>
from .client import Elasticsearch
File “/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/REPLACED-wGPJvZ3g-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py”, line 23, in <module>
from ..transport import Transport, TransportError

OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 1 of 4: Operation not permitted
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC -1 current, -1 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 2 of 4: Operation not permitted
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC -1 current, -1 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 3 of 4: Operation not permitted
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC -1 current, -1 max
```

Same code runs on local and staging env without issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a debian base image try using an alpine one.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."